# Is virtual net service endpoint available for azure application insights/log analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to figure out if virtual network service endpoint is available for azure application insights from my virtual network deployed in azure. The following article lists other azure services that offer service endpoint:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview

In azure portal, I don't see an option for application insights (or log analytics). I see the following request from internal Microsoft team:

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2063

But it is flagged as enhancement but closed without any status update (Apparently they went with private (link) endpoint option, based on the comments).

So is it available or not? Or is it in the working?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Endpoints provide access from Azure VNets through IP tagging.
All traffic to the service endpoint is limited to the Azure backbone network through routing. The public endpoint still exists; however, firewall rules limit public access.

Private Link capabilities take this a step further by providing a *private endpoint (IP address)*. As Private Links are more secure and a superset of capabilities of Service Endpoints, Private link has replaced most of the services with Service Endpoint.

I did check internally with the Application Insights team and I do not see service endpoint support in their RoadMap. *Microsoft recommends you leverage private endPoints for secure traffic routing and other features support*.